# override coupon management and guestcoupon management core vendor files magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, coupon

I want to override ***Couponmanagement.php*** of

***Magento\quote\Model\CouponManagement and guestcouponmanagemet.php*** of

***Magento\quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCouponManagement***

but my plugins are not working.PLease help me with ***di.xml*** files and what are the other files I need to create.

Comment: For which purpose you want to override?

Comment: Use pLugin instead of class rewrite

Comment: as i want to apply coupons only on those items which does not have a catalog price rule ,so i want to apply coupons individually on items of cart.can u share some screenshot or explain this without using plugin

Answer (score 0):

**Create module.xml in app/code/Test/Testmodule/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Test_Testmodule" setup_version="1.0.1">
</module>
</config>
```

**Create registration.php in app/code/Test/Testmodule and add the following code in it:**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Test_Testmodule',
__DIR__
);
```

**Create di.xml  in app/code/Test/Testmodule/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement" type="Test\Testmodule\Model\CouponManagement" /> 

</config>
```

**Override CouponManagement.php**

**create CouponManagement.php in app/code/Test/Testmodule/Model and add the following code in**

```
    <?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Test\Testmodule\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use \Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/**
 * Coupon management object.
 */
class CouponManagement implements CouponManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Constructs a coupon read service object.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository Quote repository.
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function get($cartId)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        return $quote->getCouponCode();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function set($cartId, $couponCode)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('The "%1" Cart doesn\'t contain products.', $cartId));
        }
        if (!$quote->getStoreId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Cart isn\'t assigned to correct store'));
        }
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

        try {
            $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('The coupon code couldn\'t be applied: ' .$e->getMessage()), $e);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __("The coupon code couldn't be applied. Verify the coupon code and try again."),
                $e
            );
        }
        if ($quote->getCouponCode() != $couponCode) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again."));
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function remove($cartId)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('The "%1" Cart doesn\'t contain products.', $cartId));
        }
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        try {
            $quote->setCouponCode('');
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotDeleteException(
                __("The coupon code couldn't be deleted. Verify the coupon code and try again.")
            );
        }
        if ($quote->getCouponCode() != '') {
            throw new CouldNotDeleteException(
                __("The coupon code couldn't be deleted. Verify the coupon code and try again.")
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be done without plugins?I want to know that how can I change the functionality of coupon working and how to use interface from core module.

Comment: how can we override the set() function only in this couponmanagement.php and is there any need of creating couponmanagementinterface file in Api folder app/code/Test/Testmodule

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: what should I try?

Comment: @starlord  override or not ?

Comment: yes by overriding i want to add a functionality such that coupon only applies to non discounted items in which catalog price rule is not applicable.